# Keeping non-blank comment lines with SED

Tags: bash, sed, command

I'm trying to keep only the comment lines starting with `#` that aren't blank with a sed command on a single line. I'm trying this

`sed /^#\S+/'!'d file`

However, this prints nothing.

Say the file looks something like this

```
 # comment
 # another comment
 #   
 #    
 #
 line1
 line2
 # extra comment
```

And I want

```
 # comment
 # another comment
 # extra comment`
```

My command provides no output at all. I'm trying to do this on the simplest way possible. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^[[:blank:]]*#[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]/p'
```

- The character class `[:blank:]` includes space and tab
- `^[[:blank:]]*` matches zero or more blanks at start
- `#` matches a literal `#`, then `[[:blank:]]*` matches zero or more blanks
- `[^[:blank:]]` matches any character except space or tab

Note that, not all `sed`s support expansion of special sequence `\S` to any non-whitespace.

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt
# comment
 # another comment
 #

 #

 #
 line1
 line2
 # extra comment

$ sed -n '/^[[:blank:]]*#[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]/p' file.txt
# comment
 # another comment
 # extra comment
```

Comment: This worked. I kept trying to use an approach that had the delete command, but I guess just matching and printing is easier. Very well explained as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ grep '#.*[^[:blank:]]' file
 # comment
 # another comment
 # extra comment

$ sed -n '/#.*[^[:blank:]]/p' file
 # comment
 # another comment
 # extra comment

$ awk '/#.*[^[:blank:]]/' file
 # comment
 # another comment
 # extra comment
```

Answer (score 1):

Is SED a must?
If not, you can try, for example, `grep '^\s*#.*[^\s]'` — it prints any line containing a comment sign after 0 or more whitespace characters, which also contains at least one non-whitespace character.